# How to use a variable in a Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to use a variable inside a Jquery selector:

I have 100 values on screen, called myValue11, myValue21, myValue31 etc, and I want to be able to insert data into one of these values, based on its value

```
var myVariable;


//Checking if the values are empty, if so, set 'myVariable' to a numeric value
if ($('#myValue11').val() == "")
{
   myVariable = 1;
}

else if ($('#myValue21').val() == "")
{
   myVariable = 2;
}

else if ($('#myValue31').val() == "")
{
   myVariable = 3;
}
```

//inserting into the first empty value, by using 'myVariable'

```
$('#myValue+myVariable+1').val("Hello World!");  //Doesn't work
```

The code above doesn't work, I can't seem to find a way to insert this variable into the selector, any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#myValue'+myVariable+'1').val("Hello World!");
```

You needed the extra quotes to terminate the strings.